# use variable for controller and action in @url.action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Anyone know how can i use varibale in '@Url.Action(action, controller)?EmpId=' + EmpId + '&SubModuleId=' + SubModuleId;

```
 $('.CreateEditView').click(function () {
            addloader();
            var view = $(this).attr("data-view");
            var action = $(this).attr("data-action");
            var container = $(this).attr("data-container");
            var controller = $(this).attr("data-container");
            var view = $(this).attr("data-container");
            var EmpId = $("#EmployeeId").val();
            var SubModuleId = $("#SubModuleId").val();
            var url = '@Url.Action(action, controller)?EmpId=' + EmpId + '&SubModuleId=' + SubModuleId;
            //var url = '@Url.Action("'"+action+"'", "'"+controller+"'")?EmpId=' + EmpId + '&SubModuleId=' + SubModuleId;
                             ***// action and controller doesn't exist error***
            $('#' + view + '').html("");
            $('#' + view + '').load(url);
            removeloader();
            $("#" + container + " .sucessmsg").addClass("hide");
        });
```

Comment: Use it how? Your question is not clear.

Comment: In url action i want to use variable value for action and controller, how can i pass it, please read commented lines.

Comment: You cant. I'll add a answer shortly

Comment: You cannot do that because Url.Action renders on server side and your action variable in javascript on client side

Comment: @Rohit Arora how come i can't use "@Url.Action" in javascript variable i'm able to use that in my javascript function .

Comment: @Light Read Stephen's Answer. That is more clear. In short Url.Action is already rendered on server side so you cannot include javascript variables while they are rendered on client side.

Comment: @Light You can use ' Url.Action' in javascript but cannot pass javascript variable in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action` and `controller` are javascript variables while `@Url.Action()` is razor code that is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Those variables don't yet exist (are not in scope) so you get an error.

One option would be to use

```
var url = '/' + controller + '/' + action + '?EmpId=' + EmpId + '&SubModuleId=' + SubModuleId;
```

however a better solution would be to render one data-val attribute in your elements with `class="CreateEditView"` - say `data-url="@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController")"` and then access it using `var url = $(this).data('url');`

Side note. In your `.load()` method your could also use it as

```
$('#' + view + '').load($(this).data('url'), { EmpId: EmpId, SubModuleId: SubModuleId });
```

Note however this usage (adding the parameters as an object) will mean that the `.load()` function will make a POST rather than a GET

Comment: , i have faced an issue now, This action hit on POST action rather than GET action on controller

Comment: OK, In that case ignore my last comment. If you use `.load(url, {yourParameters })` it will do a POST by default so you need to use the first option (I'll update the answer to be clearer).

Comment: `$('#' + view + '').load($(this).data('url')` how can we pass parameter in GET ?

Comment: Thanks, i have make this Get Request  `var url = $(this).data('url') + "?EmpId=" + EmpId + "&SubModuleId=" + SubModuleId;`